# How to query a objects from a list with giving a list of ids

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of object ids that I would like to retrieve from another list of object that every object has his own unique id.

```cs
List<string> idList

List<ObjectWithId> objectList

class ObjectWithId
{ 
    string Id; 
    ...
}
```

I know how to do it one by one.
But is it possible to do it in one line using LINQ?

Comment: Can you post your one by one solution ?

Comment: You should probably make `idList` a `HashSet<string>` for performance reasons.

Answer (score 7):

use this:

```
objectList.Where(m=> idList.Contains(m.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you could do this, but you need to be careful if performance is a consideration.

For example, in addition to a simple `Where`, you could use the `Join` operator as follows to find the matching objects:

```
var objects = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
        .Select(a => new ObjectWithId() { Id = a.ToString() })
        .ToList();

var ids = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 1000 / 2).Select(a => a.ToString())
    .ToList();

var matchedObjects = objects.Join(
                inner: ids,
                outerKeySelector: a => a.Id,
                innerKeySelector: a => a,
                resultSelector: (objectWithId, id) => objectWithId)
                .ToList();
```

If I contrast the performance of the above with the `.Where` operator:

```
objects.Where(m => ids.Contains(m.Id)).ToList();
```

On my computer I see this:

```
+--------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
| Method       | N         |               Mean |             Error |            StdDev |  Rank |
+--------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
| LinqJoin     | 10        |           997.5 ns |         18.938 ns |         17.714 ns |   2   |
+--------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
| LinqWhere    | 10        |           793.2 ns |          9.905 ns |          8.271 ns |   1   |
+--------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
| LinqJoin     | 1000      |       103,635.0 ns |      1,049.670 ns |        930.505 ns |   3   |
+--------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
| LinqWhere    | 1000      |     2,873,539.1 ns |     49,073.330 ns |     45,903.223 ns |   5   |
+--------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
| LinqJoin     | 10000     |     1,002,157.5 ns |     12,564.510 ns |     11,138.111 ns |   4   |
+--------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
| LinqWhere    | 10000     |   283,998,696.5 ns |  4,953,233.368 ns |  4,633,257.566 ns |   6   |
+--------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
```

In otherwords, `.Where` outperforms `.Join` when there are 10 objects, marginally. By the time we get to 1000 objects, `.Join` is outperforming it by a factor of nearly 28 - and at 10,000, by a factor of more than 280.

This is because `Join` will create an index in advance of all the keys from the object and in the list it is being joined for, internally probably using a hash. This means as it iterates the outer list, a simple lookup to this index can be done to locate a match. However, with the `.Where` and `.Contains` approach, this is essentially a nested list, with worst case O(N^2) complexity. It can only compete when there are a small numbers of items in the list, because `.Join` has the overhead of creating the index.